# How does C++ `std::unordered_map` convert from `std::pair<const Key, Value>` to `std::pair<Key, Value>`?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Being in the process of implementing a constexpr unordered map, I am trying to understand the internals of the specification of `std::unordered_map`. One thing that I am struggling to understand is how `std::pair<const Key, Value>` is converted to `std::pair<Key, Value>` without copying or moving the `Key`.

Looking at GCC's implementation ([`std::unordered_map`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/unordered_map.h), [`hashtable.h`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/hashtable.h), [`hashtable_policy.h`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/hashtable_policy.h)), as far as I understand, the `std::unordered_map` uses a `_Hashtable` under the hood which stores the items in the nodes directly as `std::pair<const Key, Value>`. However, when using the *node handle* interface of the `std::unordered_map`, the [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle) says that the key is modifiable (this is even one use case of using the node handle, to be able to change the key without having to move or copy the value):

```
key_type& key() const;
```

Also, there is a need, for example when iterating on the map, to be able to have a reference on the `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, so the same problem (but in the opposite way) arises if storing the pairs as `std::pair<Key, Value>`.

Obviously, my first intuition was simply to `const_cast` away the const, but as far as I know, this is undefined behaviour as the original data is const (and frankly, I don't even know if it's possible to `const_cast` something inside of a pair). Furthermore, in the context of doing a constexpr implementation, `const_cast` is not viable.

Just to make sure, I also checked, the following does not compile:

```
std::pair<int, int> p{1, 2};
std::pair<const int, int>& pref = p;
```

I would really appreciate if someone either has more information on how to implement this or is familiar with GCC's implementation.

Comment: As far as I am aware it is still impossible to implement the node handle interface without UB (i.e. the cast you mentioned, although it is a `reinterpret_cast`, not a `const_cast`) in user code.

Comment: In the code you link to, it uses `_Hashtable<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> ...`, the `Key` part of the table isn't `const`.

Comment: Having modifiable keys on a map type strikes me as an insanely useless interface (or rather: hard to implement correctly and efficiently, while being incredibly niche). Does your custom type *need* to implement this requirement?

Comment: @NathanOliver the `_Key` is not used for storing the key, the data is directly stored as a pair in `template<typename _Value> struct _Hash_node_value_base` (or its equivalent with the `_Value` + hash cache).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am trying to stick to the standard as much as possible to be able to use my unordered_map as a drop-in replacement, but I don't need it _per se_ (in fact, I was not aware of that node handle interface before starting this project). This is particularly useful for non-copyable non-movable types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does so by fiat.

There is no way in legal C++ to do what these functions do. However, because they're part of the C++ standard library, they are allowed to cheat. They can rely on implementation-specific behavior to do what the C++ standard demands.

You too could rely on those things, but your program's behavior would be undefined and subject to change if the implementation changes or if you use a different compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately any undefined behaviour means that it will not be constexpr, so no reinterpret_cast, no const_cast... I will probably need to drop that interface.